# Edit SPGridview on the fly like Access web part (Data sheet)

Tags: spgridview

I understand the SPGridview control now, but how do I enable the spgridview (or another control) to behave and function like the access control when in datasheet mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Datasheet mode is an ActiveX control. It is completely separate from the SPGridView.

AFAIK, you can't use the datasheet activex control in your customizations and you can't customize the control itself.

Comment: Great to know!  Thanks for the quick and fast response!